# Why does this boolean expression reduce to 1?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

The expression is: x' + x + xz + yz - which reads x not or x or x and z or y and z. This expression is the reduced form of a very large expression which I am trying to prove equal to 1.

I know the above expression is equivalent to 1 according to Wolfram and another expression reducer. Any explanation would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No boolean expression reduces to 1; 1 is not a boolean value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 4):

We'll assume that Wolfram uses 1 as a synonym for `true`. The first two terms of the expression are `x'` and `x`. One or the other of them must be 1 (`true`), so the logical OR of the two of them is 1. Then the logical OR of `true` and anything else is going to be `true`. That's why the entire expression reduces to 1.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding this expression is idea of `or` operator. If you have `true or false or smth` there is no matter what is `smth,` the expression still will be true. So in your case `xz + yz` is redundant here because `x' + x` covers all the set of possible values